# How can I put a string and an integer into the same array?

Tags: android

I have to following code. I want this to return an array e.g. `arg[]` that contains at `arg[0]` the number of the rows of my cursor and at `arg[1]` `String(0)` of my cursor. Since one is integer and the other is string I have a problem. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
    public String[] getSubcategoriesRow(String id){
    this.openDataBase();
    String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] {SECOND_COLUMN_ID,SECOND_COLUMN_SUBCATEGORIES,};
    Cursor cursor = this.dbSqlite.query(SECOND_TABLE_NAME, asColumnsToReturn, SECOND_COLUMN_SUBCATEGORIES + "= \"" + id + "\"", null, null, null, null);

    String string = cursor.getString(0);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    String arg[] = new String[]{count, string};
    cursor.close();
    return arg;
  }
```

The cursor and the results and correct i just need to compine them to an array in order to return that.

Comment: Does it have to be an array or just a mechanism for returning two values from a method?

Comment: i dont mind since i am out of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. Use an `Object[]` (an object array) instead of a `String[]` — **not recommended**, or
2. Create a new, *meaningful* class to hold the data.

   ```
   public Subcategory getSubcategoriesRow(String id){
       this.openDataBase();
       String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] {SECOND_COLUMN_ID,SECOND_COLUMN_SUBCATEGORIES,};
       Cursor cursor = this.dbSqlite.query(SECOND_TABLE_NAME, asColumnsToReturn, SECOND_COLUMN_SUBCATEGORIES + "= \"" + id + "\"", null, null, null, null);

       String string = cursor.getString(0);
       int count = cursor.getCount();
       Subcategory toReturn = new Subcategory(count, string);
       cursor.close();
       return toReturn;
     }
   ```